# How to check nth-child in laravel dusk

Tags: laravel-5.4, laravel-dusk

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
    $browser->click('.md-button:nth-child(2)');
});
```

I want to click the class element 2. How to get `nth-child class` in laravel dusk.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes using Dusk to select certain elements can be tricky. It can be done by using the `script` method as a workaround which doesn't appear in the documentation as a far as I can see. You can then execute any JavaScript inside to select any element you like. jQuery makes this easy.

Try using:

```
$browser->script('$(".md-button:nth-child(2)").click();');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can always do this by copying the css selector via your browser's dev tools. Where you right click on the element you want, then click inspect element, then when the developer tools window shows up, right click on the HTML element in the dev tools window, and select copy > copy selector, and then paste into your IDE where you're writing the test. This is a test I've run successfully as an example:

```
$this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit(new UniversityCoursesListingPage)
                ->assertVisible('.course-list-content')
                ->assertVisible('.form-control')
                ->select('.course-filter select', 'title|desc')
                ->assertSeeIn('div:nth-child(1) > article > a > h3', 'Whitepaper Training')
                ->clickLink('My Account');}
```